# PHP Losing Characters on Echo with Angle Bracket

Tags: php, html, echo

I have built a PHP function to echo some table output to a webpage.

The code to produce a header row is here:

```
echo('<tr><th class="leftcolumn">'.$headers[0].'</th>');

for ($i=1; $i<count($headers); $i++) {
    echo('<th class="normalcolumn">'.$headers[$i].'</th>');
}

echo("</tr>");
```

The output I am getting from this quite frequently has truncated close tags... Such as the following:

```
<th class="normalcolumn">Employed<br />After 2 Yrs/th>
```

I am at a loss as to what's causing this behavior. So, just to test things, I created the following simple script:

```
<?php
echo("After 2 Yrs"."</th");
?>
```

The HTML output I get from this (yes, in the view source page) is as follows:

```
After 2 Yrs
```

The extra text is notably absent.

Any ideas what the problem may be?

Comment: When I compile this locally I am seeing "</th" in the page source.  I'm using IE9 and PHP 5.3.8

Comment: Very bizarre. I'm on Chrome and I'm not sure what the PHP version is. I'll have to get back to you from work tomorrow.

I do notice that the local PHP development server has been throwing some "unexpected end of file" errors, which I find odd.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you echoing HTML?

```
<tr>
    <th class="leftcolumn"><?php echo $headers[0]; ?></th>
    <?php
        for ($i=1; $i<count($headers); $i++) {
    ?>

    <th class="normalcolumn">
        <?php echo $headers[$i]; ?>
    </th>

    <?php
        }
    ?>
</tr>
```

This way you don't need to worry about PHP having issues with HTML characters.

Comment: Certainly a valid workaround to the problem... Thanks!

Still, it would be nice to know what's causing the behavior in case I hit it again in the future.

Comment: @JohnChrysostom You posted `echo("After 2 Yrs"."</th");` as your test script. If there's no typo, then it should read as `echo("After 2 Yrs"."</th>");` I tested your original code using `$headers = array("hi", "hello", "there");` and everything came out well.

Comment: @JohnChrysostom - its not just a workaround, in all the PHP environments I've worked in this is the preferred practice. using this coding methodology, there is clear segregation of PHP and HTML code, which improves ability to maintain as well as enhance.

Comment: No, I intended to leave off the closing angle bracket on that test code. I was finding that PHP was echoing appropriately when the closing bracket was there, but that it would always fail to echo when the closing bracket wasn't there.

In the table production function, whether or not the problem appears is intermittent, which is very odd to me.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea... point well taken about the best practice. Probably better to separate HTML and PHP.

Still leaves a lingering question of why this is occurring though. As an update, I tried to recreate it using a different version of PHP running in the Apache environment last night and couldn't recreate the problem.

It's possible that this is unique to PHP 5.4.17 or that it only occurs when PHP is running its internal development web server.